# If my question is moved from one SE site to another, are the existing answers removed?

Tags: support, migrated-questions

At the suggestion of someone else, I am wondering what will happen to the existing answers in [my question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/3583) if I try to get it migrated to another stack exchange site?

The current answer on the original site has some great answers and information that I hope to preserve if the question is moved.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be off topic on the site it's on, so it doesn't merit migration to begin with.

Comment: Yes - unless a mod deletes them first.